# How to stop XP Orbs from spawning in Minecraft: Windows 10 edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Recently I have been having a lag issue with XP orbs spawning out of nowhere.

I removed all XP farms and sources of XP orbs.
I then typed `/kill @e[type=xp_orb]`, which killed all XP orbs and reduced the lag for a temporary.

The problem is that every time some XP Orbs are not being removed.

I also tried the solution in [another post regarding this issue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301482/minecraft-get-rid-of-xp-orbs) and it seems to only work for Java edition and I'm having an issue with Bedrock Edition.
I tried using MCedit but it's not working for my edition of Minecraft.

I'm tired of typing `/kill @e[type=xp_orb]` every 30 seconds or so to reduce lag, is there **any other way** of stopping XP orbs from spawning?

Comment: Can you please link the other answer you are mentioning for reference?

Comment: Fato39, Here is link: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301482/minecraft-get-rid-of-xp-orbs

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, the /kill command does indeed work, but you cannot use MCEdit to edit the world like the other answer suggested?

Comment: No, MCEdit doesn't work for me and I have to type the /kill command very often to stop the lag, Plus it destroys my chairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same command that you used:

```
kill @e[type=xp_orb]
```

However, instead of inputting it into chat, you can put it into a repeating command block set to always active, so it actively removes all xp orbs in the world. It is helpful if you disabled `commandBlockOutput` as well, to prevent chat clogs. I hope this helps, and correct me if something is wrong.